# Windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3 c# Recording Audio

Tags: c#, audio, audio-recording, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to record audio on my Rasp Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT.
I am recording audio to store in USB drive. 
Can anyone help to advise what did I do wrong.
Thanks in advance.

```
 private async void RecordBtn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //init mediacapture
        audioCapture = new MediaCapture();
        await audioCapture.InitializeAsync();

        StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> externalDrives = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
        StorageFolder usbStorage = externalDrives[0];

        var recordFolder = await usbStorage.CreateFolderAsync("Recording");

        StorageFile recordFile = await recordFolder.CreateFileAsync("record.mp3", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        audioRecording = await audioCapture.PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.High), recordFile);

        await audioRecording.StartAsync();

        isRecording = true;
        RecordStatus.Text = "Recording ... ";

        //PlayRec.IsEnabled = StopRec.IsEnabled = false;


    }

 private async void RecordBtn_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isRecording)
        {
            await audioRecording.StopAsync();
            isRecording = false;

            await audioRecording.FinishAsync();
            RecordStatus.Text = "Recording stopped.";

            //PlayRec.IsEnabled = StopRec.IsEnabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the output of your code, do you get any error?

Comment: no error during compile.. but when running it as i press on record button.. it hits unhandled exception...

Comment: Can you add the exception output to the question?

Comment: i set a breakpoint.. it didn't go pass  await audioCapture.InitializeAsync();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture audio only, try the following:

```
audioCapture = new MediaCapture();  
var settings = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();  
settings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;  
settings.MediaCategory = Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCategory.Other;  
settings.AudioProcessing = Windows.Media.AudioProcessing.Default;  
await audioCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
```

Also make sure you have set the right capabilities in your Package.appxmanifest file:

```
<Capabilities>      
   <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />  
</Capabilities>
```

Check this tutorial out, it has some good examples:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-iotcore-samples/webcam-app/

Comment: Thanks man! it works! can i know what is the reason behind it?

Comment: Did you have to add the capabilities or the settings?

Comment: I have already added the capabilities .. just wondering why my init process down't work .. do i have to setup all the parameters like in your example?

Comment: May be you don't have a Webcam, if you don't set the settings like in the answer it will try to initialize video too...

Comment: understood.. is that why it went in a loop waiting for camera ?

Comment: Can i ask additional question is I need a progress time lapse for the recording.. how can i achieve that? typically what do people use? progress bar or textblock? Sorry I have to put it this way.. because I am kind of lost and not really sure how to phrase it ..